# Vlookup using USERFORM for extracting data from another workbook without opening

Tags: excel, vba

I have have a userform that is there in Workbook A and there is a huge file say Workbook B with lot of data which i don't want to open. As soon as i press Find record button (Workbook A) on userform, VBA should be able to do Vlookup from Workbook B without opening the file. I have Done Vlookup through userform in same workbook but i am not getting it for Different Workbook

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the VLOOKUP formula in a cell and read the value from there, rather than using VLOOKUP in the VBA. You can delete the formula afterwards.